# How to convert row names into column from list based data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

I have the following list-based data-frame:

```r
df <- structure(c(5L, 300L, 251L, 42L, 187L, 16L, 2L, 249L, 158L, 17L, 77L, 
  3L, 2L, 166L, 92L, 16L, 86L, 6L, 5L, 104L, 82L, 17L, 37L, 3L, 1L, 248L, 
  239L, 10L, 81L, 2L, 0L, 136L, 107L, 6L, 24L, 3L, 6L, 164L, 147L, 18L, 83L, 
  3L, 1L, 121L, 96L, 1L, 57L, 2L, 0L, 191L, 153L, 15L, 98L, 3L, 5L, 187L, 
  200L, 8L, 83L, 2L, 1L, 289L, 211L, 19L, 113L, 3L, 2L, 169L, 80L, 13L, 48L, 
  1L), .Dim = c(6L, 12L), .Dimnames = list(c("0610005C13Rik", "0610007P14Rik", 
  "0610009B22Rik", "0610009L18Rik", "0610009O20Rik", "0610010B08Rik"), c("control", 
  "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "treated", "treated", 
  "treated", "treated", "treated", "treated")))

str(df)
#>  int [1:6, 1:12] 5 300 251 42 187 16 2 249 158 17 ...
#>  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr [1:6] "0610005C13Rik" "0610007P14Rik" "0610009B22Rik" "0610009L18Rik" ...
#>   ..$ : chr [1:12] "control" "control" "control" "control" ...
df
#>               control control control control control control treated
#> 0610005C13Rik       5       2       2       5       1       0       6
#> 0610007P14Rik     300     249     166     104     248     136     164
#> 0610009B22Rik     251     158      92      82     239     107     147
#> 0610009L18Rik      42      17      16      17      10       6      18
#> 0610009O20Rik     187      77      86      37      81      24      83
#> 0610010B08Rik      16       3       6       3       2       3       3
#>               treated treated treated treated treated
#> 0610005C13Rik       1       0       5       1       2
#> 0610007P14Rik     121     191     187     289     169
#> 0610009B22Rik      96     153     200     211      80
#> 0610009L18Rik       1      15       8      19      13
#> 0610009O20Rik      57      98      83     113      48
#> 0610010B08Rik       2       3       2       3       1
```

What I want to do is to convert row names into column I get this error:

```r
> df$gene_symbol <- rownames(df)
Warning message:
In df$gene_symbol <- rownames(df) : Coercing LHS to a list
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: It's a matrix, not a data.frame, and thus can only one type, which is currently integers.

Comment: To turn it into a tidy data.frame, maybe `library(tidyverse); df %>% t() %>% as.data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column('group') %>% gather(gene, value, -group)`

Comment: Convert the list into a dataframe: `df<-as.data.frame(df)`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as pointed out in comments, `df` is a matrix not a data frame. You can check that:

```
> class(df)
#[1] "matrix"
> typeof(df)
#[1] "integer"
```

So, as you see, `df` is a matrix of integers. Note that the data in matrix can only be of the same type while in data frame, you can store data of different types. This is how matrix and data frame objects are different.

To achieve what you are after, you can convert matrix `df` to a data frame and then do what you want:

```
newdf <- data.frame(df)
> class(newdf)
#[1] "data.frame"
newdf$gene_symbol <- rownames(newdf)
```

Done!